# Average - EF generic repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I want to add method for computing average to my entity framework generic repository. Can I do this really generic? What method should I use? Here is something I am thinking about (this is just bad example as a starting point)

```
    public double GetAverage(string property, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null) 
    {
        return BuildQuery(filter).Select(property).Average();
    }
```

Or doing this generic is bad idea and I should create also specific interface for specific entity, where the implemntation is clear?

My repo now is

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    void Delete(object id);
    void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete);

    TEntity GetFirst(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = "");

    IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = "");

    PagedList<TEntity> GetPaged(int pageSize, int pageNumber, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = "");

    TEntity GetByID(object id);
    void Insert(TEntity entity);
    void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate);
    }
```

BuildQuery is:

```
private IQueryable<TEntity> BuildQuery(
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
    string includeProperties = "")
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = _dbSet;

    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }

    foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
        (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        query = query.Include(includeProperty);
    }

    if (orderBy != null)
    {
        return orderBy(query);
    }
    else
    {
        return query;
    }
}
```

Comment: *I have an architectural design problem when using entity framework, i decided to use the repository pattern and abstract everything behind a redundant layer, now i have lots more architectural design problems*

Comment: What should be a computed average of let's say `["abc", "cba", 3, "ddd"]` ? (remember that `TEntity` could be of type `object`

Comment: I know doing this by generic might be bad idea. I can still use specific interface (non generic) for specific entity.

Comment: Just drop all this stuff and use entity framework directly, or at least expose `IQueryable<TEntity>` from your "repository", and let caller do whatever it needs with that.